Viewing variable values in Visual Studio code using Rust and CodeLLDB
When I am stepping through the code in the debugger, I've noticed that certain variables don't show values in the variables pane:

Options: if a variable is an option, it doesn't show the value of the object in the option (if there is one). I believe it shows a ptr or other value
HashMaps: I can't view the objects within the hashmap or their values.

Local variables (e.g., String, u64) show values normally.
Is this by design, or is there a way to view these values to make debugging easier? Thanks!


Being able to see variables depends a lot on whether the compiler and the debugger fit together.
For example, if you run CodeLLDB, you want to make sure that your code is compiled with the GDB backend, not with the MSVC backend.
On the other hand, if you do compile with the MSVC backend, the ms-vscode.cpptools debugger might work better for you.
You can choose the debugger that rust-analyzer uses at:
Settings -> Extensions -> rust-analyzer -> debug -> Debug: Engine
You can switch the compiler toolchain by calling (assuming you are on windows):

rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
rustup default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu

(followed by cargo clean)
On Windows 11, I got the best results with:

x86_64-pc-windows-gnu + vadimcn.vscode-lldb (CodeLLDB)
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc + ms-vscode.cpptools

In those configurations, both were able to resolve the content of a HashMap.

Thanks, I tried x86_64-pc-windows-gnu + vadimcn.vscode-lldb. I get different output in the debugger now, but still can't see values in the hashmap. I've added a screenshot to the original post.
FYI that hashmap in this case is HashMap<u64, Fork>, where Fork is a Struct I created.

Hm. Works for me, so I'm unsure how to help you further :/ If that doesn't work, then it's probably a restriction of the debugger

After further testing, I think it does work. Thanks for the help!
